# Generators and Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples, generator

Be kind, I'm still learning python (but getting better).  I've looked at the other posts regarding generators, and haven't found an answer to my specific question.  Sorry, if I missed it.

So I am writing a method that acts as a generator.  I can make it work, but not the way I want it to.  I'm trying to understand generators.

If I write the following:

```
def genfunc(self):
    """
    self.some_lst is defined in __init__ as a list of tuples. e.g [(1,2),(2,3)]
    """
    yield (x for x in self.some_lst)
```

I get

```
Line 73: TypeError: '<invalid type>' does not support indexing
```

however, if I write it as:

```
def genfunc()
    """
    self.some_lst is defined in __init__ as a list of tuples. e.g [(1,2),(2,3)]
    """
    for x in self.some_lst:
        yield x
```

Everything works fine.

Two questions:  1. What am I fundamentally missing about generators?   and 2. Is there a way to write this in one line as I tried (but failed) to do?

I know there are some SOers just waiting to help this newb out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing *generator expressions* with your generator.

`yield` yields whatever follows, and you have put a generator expression there. Just like a generator *function*, this produces a generator object:

```
>>> (x for x in some_lst)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x100544aa0>
```

This is what you yielded.

Because you essentially yielded another generator, you couldn't index it, as it was not yielding the 2-value tuples you were expecting.

Since the generator expression itself produces a generator, you could just return that generator expression *directly*, without using `yield`:

```
def genfunc(self):
    """
    self.some_lst is defined in __init__ as a list of tuples. e.g [(1,2),(2,3)]
    """
    return (x for x in self.some_lst)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python2, you need to write

```
def genfunc():
    for x in self.some_lst:
        yield x
```

but in Python3 you could write

```
def genfunc():
    yield from self.some_lst
```

See [PEP380 -- Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).

---

```
yield (x for x in self.some_lst)
```

does not work since `(x for x in self.some_lst)` is an object -- a generator expression. So the `yield` expression merely yields that one object, not the items inside that generator expression.

Comment: Thanks, my confusion comes from the fact that "print max(x for x in range(10)) works.  I guess it is the yield, that makes the difference.

Comment: @user3641109: that is a generator expression too; `max()` loops over it.

Comment: @user3641109: `max(x for x in range(10))` is equivalent to `max( (x for x in range(10)) )`. So `max` is being applied to a generator expression. Some operators, such a `max` and `sum` [allow the parentheses around the generator expression to be omitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799459/why-can-you-omit-the-surrounding-parentheses-for-generators-in-python-when-passi).