# Summing certain numbers from a nested list of integers

Tags: python, nested, iteration

I want to sum all second members of a nested list's sub-lists,

such that :

```
list = [[an integer,integer to be added], [another integer, integer to be added], [...], [...], [...], [...],....]
```

I tried to use built-in functions like map or iteration.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to sum all second members of a nested list's sub-lists

Using `sum` and a simple generator comprehension will do.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> sum(sublist[1] for sublist in lst)
6
```

To make it more understandable / add some explanation:

```
>>> [sublist[1] for sublist in lst]
[2, 4]
```

creates a list of all second elements for every sublist in your list.
We pass that to the `sum` function (with the minor difference that we are actually passing a generator to save memory, but `sum([sublist[1] for sublist in lst])` would work just fine as well).

Comment: By the way, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799459/why-can-you-omit-the-surrounding-parentheses-for-generators-in-python-when-passi)'s why you can omit an extra set of parentheses when passing a generator to a function.