# any/all() argument expression : list or generator?

Tags: python, list, generator

in the expression, `any(not (i % 6) for i in range(1, 10))`

does the `any()` argument `not (i % 6) for i in range(1, 10)` defines a generator or a list ?

For the moment I understand that in:

```
g = (not (i % 6) for i in range(1, 10))
```

`g` is a generator

and in :

```
l = [not (i % 6) for i in range(1, 10)]
```

`l` is a list

But as we don't invoke `any` with `[]` or `()`, like in `any([not (i % 6) for i in range(1, 10)])` or `any((not (i % 6) for i in range(1, 10)))` I'm confused...

Comment: Thank you for the link ! Unless I get something wrong, my question is more related to what happens internally when you pass the expression to any(), is it evaluated as a list of as a generator ? (And not to answer the question to choose one or another)

Comment: If there are no `[ ]` there is no list

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799459/why-can-you-omit-the-surrounding-parentheses-for-generators-in-python-when-passi

Comment: `any` and `all` accept an iterable. Which can be a list, a generator and any other type that can be iterated over.

Comment: Thank you ! with https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#id14 and the @DeepSpace answer, I think I got it ! (too bad that the question was closed, I think the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799459/why-can-you-omit-the-surrounding-parentheses-for-generators-in-python-when-passi is pretty evasive when 'If there are no [ ] there is no list' provides a very clear answer)